# on click interface callback gives null in Android

Tags: java, android

I have Android module library which will create the Touch Keypad UI and set event listener for done and backbutton.

Also have main activity with implement eventCallback interface

> MainActivity.java (Appication)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements eventCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View v = new touchkey(this);
        setContentView(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        Log.i("test","complete");
        Toast.makeText(this, "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

> eventCallback.java (Android Module Library)

```
public interface eventCallback {
    void onClick();
}
```

> touchkey.java (Android Module Library)

```
public class touchkey extends RelativeLayout{
    private static touchkey INSTANCE;
    TextView bclear;
    ImageView bdone;

    eventCallback eventCall;


    public touchkey(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize(context);
    }


    public touchkey(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize(context);
    }
    public void test() {
        Log.i("test","test");
    }

    private void initialize(Context context) {
        inflate(context, R.layout.touchkey, this);


        bclear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_clear);
        bdone = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_done);


        bdone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (eventCall != null) {
                    eventCall.onClick();
                }
            }
        });

        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

but iam getting nullpointer exception on the touchkey.java

> eventCall.onClick(); (eventCall is null)

I dont know where i am doing things wrong. can anybody help on this. Requirement: i need to handle the click event happening on the Library in Main Activity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create `setter` for eventCall (in touchkey.java):

```
public void setEventCall(eventCallback eventCall) {
    this.eventCall = eventCall;
}
```

And, use it (in MainActivity):

```
View v = new touchkey(this);
setContentView(v);
((touchkey) v).setEventCall(this);
```